# Accessing a 3d array without using foreach loop

Tags: php

Let's say I have a 3D array and I don't want to access it through the key names.

Is there a way to access to the value (2) without having to use a `foreach` loop?

```
array (size=1)
'type' => 
 array (size=1)
  'registered' => string '2' (length=1)
```

Comment: Can you post a `print_r()` output of your array?

Comment: If you don't know the key names, do you know the value?

Comment: you can use `array_keys($array)` to get the keys, but foreach is a better solution.

Comment: it's not that i don't know the key, i just don't want to use them

Comment: What should be the reason for not to? I'm curious about this particularity

Comment: @JorgeCampos because i am trying to do a general method. The array i've posted is the short version, it could have another subarray with key 'notregistered' and value 1.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant the thing is that i am trying to finde another way of accessing without the foreach because the maximum of subarrays that the array can have is 2

Comment: @Jimena Then use a boolean: `registered = true` or `registered = false`

Comment: @Sébastien yes i know that is possible, but i am trying to find another way so my code doesn't get much longer

Comment: Your code *will* be longer the way you are doing it. And needlessly more complex.

Comment: I might be trolling but /technically/ you can do this without a foreach loop or indexes by using the old school array functions (current, key, next, etc) and building a copy of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible without a loop.

1. If you don't want to use keys and all that matters is the position within the array then use a numerical array.
2. If you really want to use an associative array and you need to find the key at a specified index, then at some point you will need to loop through your array.

Answer (score 1):

You could try serializing your array and working with the serialized structure.  Not saying this is good or even viable, but it might do what you want.

You can find out more about serialize here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: i've tried serializing (not that way), but founded that wasn't much helpful for building the query